# Subindo projeto node.js (com websocket) para o Heroku

Tags: node.js, websocket, heroku

O projeto é este: http://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder-projects/projects/blinky_lights/

Segui todos esses passos:

```
Heroku login

ssh-keygen -t rsa

heroku keys:add

Procfile 
(web: tilestream --host neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com --host '*' --uiPort=$PORT --tilePort=$PORT --tiles=./tiles)

heroku create

heroku labs:enable websockets

git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:seu-app-name.git

git push heroku master

-----> Writing a custom .npmrc to circumvent npm bugs
-----> Exporting config vars to environment
-----> Installing dependencies
       npm WARN package.json consolidate@0.8.0 No repository field.
       npm WARN package.json express-params@0.0.3 No repository field.
       npm WARN package.json mustache@0.7.2 No repository field.
-----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds
-----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts
-----> Building runtime environment
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 14.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v3
       http://neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Hero
```

Cigano

```
root@coder:/backup# heroku logs
2014-06-05T15:13:03.928437+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by neuberfran@bol.com.br
2014-06-05T15:13:03.929255+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by neuberfran@bol.com.br
2014-06-05T15:19:23+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-06-05T15:19:46+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-06-05T15:19:49.610513+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: tilestream: command not found
2014-06-05T15:19:46.624287+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c20c9f1 by neuberfran@bol.com.br
2014-06-05T15:19:46.504770+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by neuberfran@bol.com.br
2014-06-05T15:19:46.624389+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by neuberfran@bol.com.br
2014-06-05T15:19:50.775922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-05T15:19:50.776898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-05T15:19:50.765465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-06-05T15:19:48.908599+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `tilestream --host neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com --host '*' --uiPort=37916 --tilePort=37916 --tiles=./tiles`
2014-06-05T15:19:53.891031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `tilestream --host neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com --host '*' --uiPort=42142 --tilePort=42142 --tiles=./tiles`
2014-06-05T15:19:55.656337+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: tilestream: command not found
2014-06-05T15:19:57.470998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-05T15:19:57.459609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-06-05T15:20:01.414382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=neuberfranlight2.herokuapp.com request_id=b2e526cd-0c83-43f1-9e18-c948a7dc7739 fwd="177.106.83.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T15:20:01.931195+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=neuberfranlight2.herokuapp.com request_id=e532137a-9bd4-4d5e-9484-7b632d325457 fwd="177.106.83.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T15:20:02.152067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=neuberfranlight2.herokuapp.com request_id=1bcc67d0-ba41-40d6-9d7b-13dd2913f17c fwd="177.106.83.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T15:20:06.511712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=neuberfranlight2.herokuapp.com request_id=5d4a803c-4879-41b8-bc19-b2af7676da65 fwd="177.106.83.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T15:25:10.643786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=a942c3a7-7932-461d-9974-1ca025f0a18c fwd="177.106.83.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T15:25:11.060255+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=c5c8a91a-48a9-4f8d-ba60-83e604e9e206 fwd="177.106.83.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 by
tes=
2014-06-05T15:25:11.287877+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=b34b2122-ce2c-40db-b67f-7ebcaf83d80e fwd="177.106.83.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T15:26:37.513012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=3c41e3ee-9275-4bb7-b452-9d1f7fd1979d fwd="177.106.83.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T15:43:09.958789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-05T15:43:14.298030+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: tilestream: command not found
2014-06-05T15:43:15.821049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-05T15:43:15.809989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-06-05T15:43:12.922824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `tilestream --host neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com --host '*' --uiPort=26787 --tilePort=26787 --tiles=./tiles`
2014-06-05T16:01:11.305215+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=9c533405-77ae-42e3-8dd2-36c054133ef6 fwd="146.164.9.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T16:01:12.357053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=3b4d59e2-be06-4a82-8e9a-acdce5f57a7f fwd="146.164.9.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T16:11:18.785280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=99500615-0d79-4f44-be95-534eb89e68c5 fwd="54.237.214.217" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T16:25:34.524432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=1eb005a1-22fe-4e7e-b713-badf4bd6e411 fwd="200.229.198.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T16:25:35.703204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=a87b8a35-73b7-402f-8bca-19e5bcb61082 fwd="200.229.198.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T16:51:06.670209+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-05T16:51:10.040070+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: tilestream: command not found
2014-06-05T16:51:11.312395+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-05T16:51:09.090355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `tilestream --host neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com --host '*' --uiPort=51353 --tilePort=51353 --tiles=./tiles`
2014-06-05T16:51:11.301487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-06-05T17:21:26.879152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=f8d51e7a-36ef-4f8c-9988-7cd3e0e67d0a fwd="172.23.21.196, 186.215.116.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-05T17:21:27.384852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com request_id=01e2d601-5cb9-40cd-8e07-fe9c66470adc fwd="172.23.21.196, 186.215.116.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
root@coder:/backup#
```

Como base para criar o

***"var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5001);
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
})"***

usei estes dois tópicos:

http://pi.gadgetoid.com/article/running-google-coder-on-your-existing-raspberry-pi-or-desktop-pc

http://jsantisi.com/tag/tilestream/

Cigano,

trata-se do Procfile

```
(web: tilestream --host neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com --host '*' --uiPort=$PORT --tilePort=$PORT --tiles=./tiles)
```

Conforme este site: http://jsantisi.com/tag/tilestream/

de onde tire o tal Procfile. Imaginei que tilestream não influenciaria em nada no final do deploy

este cara é o "mentor" do projeto:

> http://forum.fazedores.com/t/campus-party-2014-luis-leao/131

ficaria realmente grato se você me ajudasse a realizá-lo.

Comment: Olá! Não estou muito familiarizado com essas tecnologias, mas não me parece muito claro qual é exatamente o problema que está enfrentando. Talvez seja interessante complementar sua pergunta com informações adicionais que ajudem os usuários a respondê-la.

Comment: Você seguiu as instruções de instalação do Tilestream segundo o site colocado na pergunta?

Comment: O projeto meu é outro. No lugar do tilestream devo por o que ?

Comment: Não sei. Não conheço seu projeto, nem essa tecnologia. Só conheço o deploy do Heroku mesmo.

Comment: Verifique se algum dos seguintes links pode te ajudar: - http://www.spatialanalysis.ca/2014/deploying-tilestream-to-the-heroku-cloud/ - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

Answer (score 1):

O deploy ocorreu sem erros. Tentei entrar no seu site e tive a seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ver os logs de erro, use:

```
heroku logs
```

Há [mais opções adicionais aqui](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging).

### EDIT

Novamente, o erro é claro. Na linha

```
Starting process with command `tilestream --host neuberfranlights.herokuapp.com --host '*' --uiPort=51353 --tilePort=51353 --tiles=./tiles`
```

O Heroku tenta chamar um comando chamado `tilestream` e levanta o seguinte erro:

```
bash: tilestream: command not found
```

Não sei o que é este `tilestream`, mas é alguma coisa que sua aplicação precisa. Posso continuar ajudando se eu tiver mais informações sobre este projeto.